# How to write this PHP regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string of numbers surrounded by parenthesis:

```
(2)(56)(9)(12)(2)
```

I was given the following regex by someone to split the numbers out of their parentheses:

```
<?php

$string = '(2)(56)(9)(12)(2)';

$pattern = "/\\)\\(|\\(|\\)?/";

$numbers = preg_split($pattern, $string);

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo $number.'<br />';
}

?>
```

This outputs:

```
<br />
<br />
2<br />
<br />
5<br />
6<br />
<br />
9<br />
<br />
1<br />
2<br />
<br />
2<br />
<br />
<br />
```

When I really need it to output:

```
2<br />
56<br />
9<br />
12<br />
2<br />
```

How can the regex be altered to make it work?

**p.s. each number in between the parenthesis can be of an unlimited length.**

Comment: The original regex uses too much escaping. A single backslash each would suffice. (Wouldn't fix it, just an aside note.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY option of preg_split, and a small change in the pattern:

```
$pattern = "/\\)\\(|\\(|\\)/"; // removed the "?"
$numbers = preg_split($pattern, $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); // added PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
```

Or use preg_match:

```
$string = '(2)(56)(9)(12)(2)';

preg_match_all('#\d+#', $string, $matches);

foreach ($matches[0] as $number) {
    echo "$number<br />\n";
}
```

Output:

```
2<br />
56<br />
9<br />
12<br />
2<br />
```

Answer (score 3):

I would not use preg_split in the first place. If that's really your source string, then look just for numbers:

```
preg_match_all("/\d+/", $string, $numbers);
print_r($numbers[0]);
```

Comment: @akond: yes, but if you're looking for digits, it's best to specify that, right?

Comment: Better to be specific. Yet it's a peculiar subject to begin with. Maybe `[^()]+` would be most appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

First, there's an error in the regex.  It should be:

```
$pattern = "/\\)\\(|\\(|\\)/";
```

Note the last `?` is removed.

The easy answer is to just check for empty numbers:

```
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    if ($number !== '') {
        echo $number.'<br />';
    }
}
```

Note the strict `!==` test since `0` may be a valid number...

Or, add the [`PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`](https://www.php.net/preg_split) option to the `preg_split` call:

```
$numbers = preg_split($pattern, $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Another option is to use [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/fa/function.preg-match-all.php) with the simple regex: `/\d+/`:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $string, $matches);

$numbers = $matches[0];
```

Comment: Notice that the OP is getting `56` split to `5` and `6`

Answer (score 2):

Use `preg_match` instead of split and use `/\\d+/` as your expression

Try

```
$string = '(2)(56)(9)(12)(2)';

$pattern = "/\d+/";

preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $numbers);

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo $number.'<br />';
}
```

I'm not sure on PHP regex syntax either `\\d` or `\d`

Comment: I didn't say *"You have to use `preg_match`"*  I said *"Use  `preg_match`"* - This is my suggestion. :)

Answer (score 1):

Pass the flag `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` to not return empty tokens and remove the `?` which allows for an empty separator. You also don't need to double-escape the `()`'s in PHP. Using `preg_match` on `(\d+)` looks like it would be a simpler solution to your problem though.

```
$string = '(2)(56)(9)(12)(2)';
$pattern = "/\)\(|\(|\)/";
$numbers = preg_split($pattern, $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo "$number<br />\n";
}
```

Output:

```
2<br />
56<br />
9<br />
12<br />
2<br />
```

http://ideone.com/zxvYi